# Failed ruby push to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, push

I am trying to 'git push heroku master' but am receiving:

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.9), and Bundler cannot continue.

Consequently, I am told that the push is rejected as the Ruby app has failed to compile.

Here is Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.4'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Any idea why this error is appearing? I've been having issues getting this to work for the better part of the evening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Again - could you please paste the output you get from `git push heroku`?

Comment: @BroiSatse Believe I solved this issue, deleted Gemfile.lock, then re-installed bundle. Seemed to work... not sure why.

Comment: Voting to close this question as a non-reproducible issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You cannot use sqlite on Heroku.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3)

> If you’ve removed the gem 'sqlite3 line from your Gemfile and are still getting errors while deploying to Heroku it is likely that another gem you are using has sqlite3 as a dependency. To help find the source of this dependency look in your Gemfile.lock for sqlite3. Find the gem that has sqlite3 as a dependency and remove it from your Gemfile. Once you’ve done this run bundle install and ensure that sqlite3 no longer exists in your Gemfile.lock.

Comment: http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/create_and_deploy_a_rails_app?back=create_a_heroku_account Section 7.2 ?

Comment: He is using postgres in production.

Comment: @Zack And did you remember to `bundle` after moving `sqlite` to `:development, :test`?

Comment: @BroiSatse This issue is because `sqlite` is included in the `Gemfile.lock`, as the linked page explains.